# slow drop down menu CSS

Tags: html, css

Found lots of advice on website how to. I am try to make it work but is different kind of dropdown menu. I try to get a slow falling css drop down menu.
here is html -

Most help comes in the form of list boxed nav bard but I prefer this method, it position nicely.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: crosshair;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000000;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline;
}
/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  color: #000000;
}
.dropdown1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}
.dropdown2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 220px;
}
.dropdown3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 615px;
}
.dropdown4 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 1003px;
}
.pageheading {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 210px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.pageparagraph {
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: justify;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 290px;
  right: 685px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.logo {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
body {
  background-image: url("ForestBackground.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.arrow1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 166px;
  left: 185;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.arrow2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 166px;
  left: 580;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.arrow3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 166px;
  left: 970;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.arrow4 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 166px;
  left: 1130;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .arrow1 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .arrow2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .arrow3 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .arrow4 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button class="dropbtn">Climate Change
      <div class="arrow1">&#10162;</div>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/mash/highland-burgundy-red-1kg/">Greenhouse Gases</a>
      <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/mash/arran-victory-1kg/">Carbon Dioxide</a>
      <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/mash/desiree-1kg/">Methane</a>
      <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/salad/belle-de-fontenay-1kg/">Water Vapour</a>
      <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/salad/belle-de-fontenay-1kg/">NF3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i would like a falling, slide down menu as opposed to a fade in any suggestions friends?

edit - just editing this to say thanks for all the help! and mainly to help get my account able to ask questions again, I don't know why i have been banned. please help. love to you all.

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem. You want to slow down the dropdown but do not know how?

Comment: Have you thought about adding a CSS animation?
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp
Or just increase the transition to a higher number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/btLjk40x/2/ ~ check this fiddle

```
.dropdown-content {
    overflow: hidden:
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    height: 200px; // sample height
}
```

Comment: thanks vmuch but didnt seem to work for me, looking more for a slide down rather than a fade in, any suggestions?

Comment: do you need it to be pure css?

Comment: thanks, this works, but for some of the menus it goes down too far and for others it doesnt go all the way to the bottom?

Comment: you need to change the height of every dropdown-content to the exact height you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emulate a "slide-down" effect you can add an extra wrapper to your submenu elements and use `translate` like this:

> **Warning:** You are using a lot of fixed positions that will lead you into issues later for responsive layouts and some are unnecessary like the ones for the arrows

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: crosshair;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.dropdown-content > div {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  transform:translateY(-100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition:transform 1s;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000000;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content > div {
  transform:translateY(0);
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  color: #000000;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}
.dropdown2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 220px;
}
.dropdown3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 615px;
}
.dropdown4 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 1003px;
}
.pageheading {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 210px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.pageparagraph {
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: justify;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 290px;
  right: 685px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.logo {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
body {
  background-image: url("ForestBackground.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.arrow1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 166px;
  left: 185;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.arrow2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 166px;
  left: 580;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.arrow3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 166px;
  left: 970;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.arrow4 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 166px;
  left: 1130;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .arrow1 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .arrow2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .arrow3 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover .arrow4 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button class="dropbtn">Climate Change
      <div class="arrow1">&#10162;</div>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div>
        <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/mash/highland-burgundy-red-1kg/">Greenhouse Gases</a>
        <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/mash/arran-victory-1kg/">Carbon Dioxide</a>
        <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/mash/desiree-1kg/">Methane</a>
        <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/salad/belle-de-fontenay-1kg/">Water Vapour</a>
        <a href="https://thepotatoshop.com/shop/salad/belle-de-fontenay-1kg/">NF3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wowzer, this worked! to an extent... it slides down but it is visible above the drop down menu!